# Angular Directive not Firing Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to know if someone experienced this before:

`CustomDirective.ngAfterContentInit` not being fired.

I have a problem with the `routerLinkActive` not adding the `active` class to a link when the page is refreshed or manually accessed:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign=" stretch" fxLayoutGap="5px">
  <a fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="center center"
     routerLinkActive="active"
     [routerLink]="['profile']">Profile</a>
  ...
</div>
```

I've tried to figure out what's happening, discarding conflicts with the `flex-layout` directives, applied it to different HTML elements, I even built a plunker with a basic app to report the issue, and `routerLinkActive` worked well, so it wasn't a general problem, maybe just for complex apps, I don't know.

I opted to fork the directive to be able to debug it internally and got stuck when I realized that `ngAfterContentInit` was not being fired, in fact, only `ngOnInit`, `ngDoCheck` and `ngOnChanges` are fired.

This means, that when `@ContentChildren` are fetched, I have no easy way to detect them through `ngAfterContentInit`, and that's being a problem for the core `routerLinkActive`.

I have another directive of mine in the same component, which *triggers all the lifecycle hooks*, so I got lost on my assumptions of why `myForkedLinkActive` does not trigger all of them. I commented out a lot of code, and still didn't work! sometimes even `ngOnChanges` wasn't fired! so I'm smelling some conflict that causes the `View` to not trigger the hooks correctly.

My only option in the meantime is to use `ngDoCheck` and an `initialized` flag to detect the moment `@ContentChildren` retrieves the children and simulate the call to `ngAfterContentInit`.

Someone got an idea of what could be happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have plunker example that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @yurzui no, I've tried to build it http://embed.plnkr.co/3Mo5sX/ but in a simple app, I found that it works perfectly. My app consists of a lot of modules and subroutes, so I don't know if it's worth of replication and later disappointment if the issue doesn't show.